# JavaScript nth degree tree

Tags: javascript, algorithm, tree, depth-first-search

1. I need to change the clicked property to true of a parent if all children clicked are true. so in this case ID - 14,15 is having clicked property to true. So, parents having ID 11 clicked has to be made true.
2. If 11,12,14,15 are true then then 4 has to be made true.

```
let obj = {children:[
{
    ID:1,
    clicked: false,
    children: [
        {
            ID:4,
            clicked: false,
            children: [
                {
                    ID:11,
                    clicked: false,
                    children: [
                                {
                                    ID:14,
                                    clicked: true,
                                },
                                {
                                    ID:15,
                                    clicked: true,
                                }
                            ]
                },
                {
                    ID:12,
                    clicked: false,
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            ID:5,
            clicked: false,
        }
    ]
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: what goes wrong? do you want to mutate the data or gat a new tree?

Comment: @Nina Scholz, thanks for the reply. A new tree or the change of the existing tree is okay with me. I want the data to be in the required format on call of a method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nina gave a great answer for when you want to mutate the input.

Here is a simple one which creates a new object:

```js
const consolidate = ({clicked, children = [], ...rest}, _, __, kids = children .map (consolidate)) => ({
  ...rest, 
  clicked: clicked || (kids .length > 0) && kids .every (k => k .clicked),
  ...(kids .length ? {children: kids} : {})
})

const obj1 = {children: [{ID: 1, clicked: false, children: [{ID: 4, clicked: false, children: [{ID: 11, clicked: false, children: [{ID: 14, clicked: true}, {ID: 15, clicked: true}]}, {ID: 12, clicked: false}]}, {ID: 5, clicked: false}]}]};
//  with 12 switched to `true`
const obj2 = {children: [{ID: 1, clicked: false, children: [{ID: 4, clicked: false, children: [{ID: 11, clicked: false, children: [{ID: 14, clicked: true}, {ID: 15, clicked: true}]}, {ID: 12, clicked: true}]}, {ID: 5, clicked: false}]}]};

console .log ('obj1', consolidate (obj1))
console .log ('obj2', consolidate (obj2))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

We recur on the `children`, if any, and then regenerate the object evaluating the `clicked` property of each.

Comment: could you please help me with [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71347855/nth-order-tree-make-all-parents-false-if-any-one-of-last-child-is-true)

Comment: You will need to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71347855/edit) that question to include your attempt and explanations for what went wrong before people will vote to reopen it.   Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and read up on [asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Answer (score 2):

You could take a [depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) algorithm and if all of the children contains `clicked: true`, the parent gets an update.

```js
const
    update = object => {
        if (!object.children) return object.clicked;
        return object.clicked = object.children.every(update);
    },
    object = { children: [{ ID: 1, clicked: false, children: [{ ID: 4, clicked: false, children: [{ ID: 11, clicked: false, children: [{ ID: 14, clicked: true }, { ID: 15, clicked: true }] }, { ID: 12, clicked: false }] }, { ID: 5, clicked: false }] }] };

update(object);

console.log(object);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Nina Scholz
The above code is making id 4  true, but what I want is that only the parent of the 14 and 15 to be made true. ie the id 11. Since 12 is false the 4 must be false.

If all the child are true the that particular parent must be true, 

If 11,12,14,15 is true then 4 must be made true

if  4 , 5 , 11 , 12, 14 , 15 is true then 1 must be true.

Comment: please see edit.

Comment: Thank you so much...............
I tested with few use cases it works like charm.
You saved my day.

Comment: please check the lates edition. it visits now all nodes.

Comment: Checked Nina scholz , it works great. Thank you :)

Comment: could you please help me with [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71347855/nth-order-tree-make-all-parents-false-if-any-one-of-last-child-is-true)